# React Form onChange doesn't update state

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I am getting a wierd behaviour when i input into my password `<input/>`. Every time I input something into it the state doesn't change but it console.logs. The same thing doesn't happen with email field and when i try to submit the form the password is empty... What am I doing wrong?

This is my react component:

```
  5 export default class Login extends React.Component {
  6   state: {
  7     email: string,
  8     password: string,
  9   };
 10
 11   handleEmailChange: (e: any) => void;
 12   handlePasswordChange: (e: any) => void;
 13   handleButtonPress: () => void;
 14
 15   constructor() {
 16     super();
 17     this.state = { email: '', password: '' };
 18
 19     this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
 20     this.handlePasswordChange = this.handleButtonPress.bind(this);
 21     this.handleButtonPress = this.handleButtonPress.bind(this);
 22   };
 23
 24   handleEmailChange(e: any) {
 25     this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
 26   };
 27
 28   handlePasswordChange(e: any) {
 29     this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
 30   };
 31
 32   handleButtonPress() {
 33     axios.post('/api/users/login', {
 34       email: this.state.email,
 35       password: this.state.password,
 36     })
 37     .then((response: any) => {
 38       console.log(response.data);
 39     })
 40     .catch((error: any) => {
 41       console.log(error);
 42     });
 43   };
 44
 45   render() {
 46     return (
 47       <div>
 48         <input
 49           type="email"
 50           onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
 51           placeholder="Enter email"
 52         />
 53         <input
 54           type="password"
 55           onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
 56           placeholder="Enter password"
 57         />
 58         <button onClick={this.handleButtonPress}>
 59           Login!
 60         </button>
 61       </div>
 62     );
 63   }
 64 }
```

Here is the screenshot of what happens when i go the enter the password:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error in line-20.

```
this.handlePasswordChange = this.handleButtonPress.bind(this);
```

it should be

```
this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Side Note:**

Using ES6 You can refactor / combine *handleEmailChange* and *handlePasswordChange* 
into:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
 this.setState({
   [e.target.name]:e.target.value 
 });
}
```